# Why Output of c++ code changes when I change the function return type?

Tags: c++

```
class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1(5, 5);
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code has output as `10 20` but when I change the return type of 
`Test &setX` to `Test setX` and `Test &setY` to `Test setY`, the output changes to `10 5`. Can anyone explain the reason for the same ? This is not an assignment quoestion or anything related to homework.

Comment: Looks like you want to design a so called **fluent** interface. In which case, you should always return a reference. Because you want all the fluent operations to be executed on one given object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is all about temporary object.

In the version without return reference, i.e. return type is `Test`
Your code is equivalent to

```
Test obj1(5, 5);
Test temp1 = obj1.setX(10);
Test temp2 = temp1.setY(20);
// temp2 will have x = 10 and y = 20, but the object is discarded
obj1.print();
```

as you can see `setY(20)` is called on an temporary object, and the returned value is discarded. So only the first `setX(10)` actually modify `obj1`

On the other hand, if you return a reference, i.e. the return type is `Test &`, no temporary will be created. So both `setX(10)` and `setY(20)` will affect the original object (`obj1`), because the method are called on a same object.

Answer (score 4):

In the following line when you return a value (and not a reference) you end up having the obj1.setX(10) returning a new object. On this new object (that will be discarded) setY is called but the original remains unchanged

```
obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you change `Test &setX(int a)` into `Test setX(int a)`, the function `Test setX(int a)` returns a new object. `obj1.setX(10).setY(20)` equal to the follows:

```
  Test newobj = obj1.setX(10);
  newobj.setY(20);

  obj1.print();      // 10, 5
  newobj.print();    // 10, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
obj1.setX(10);
obj1.setY(20);
```

result always will be 10 and 20.